# Recurring action handler

Tags: c#

In my application I have a class responsible to save in a file the current status of the application (model) when it change :

```
public class BackupAgent
{
    private readonly Model _model;

    public BackupAgent(Model model)
    {
        _model = model;
        _model.Changed += Save;
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        // serialize model and save it to a file
        ...
    }
}
```

It works fine but when there is a lot of modification the file is written again and again.

I came out with a `RecurringActionHandler` that ensure that

- the `Save` method is not called twice in a minimum amount of time.
- the `Save` method is always called (sooner or later) after a modification.

It is used like that:

```
public class BackupAgent
{
    private readonly Model _model;
    private readonly RecurringActionHandler _saveHandler;

    public BackupAgent(Model model)
    {
        _model = model;
        _saveHandler = new RecurringActionHandler(Save, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

        _model.Changed += RequestSave;
    }

    private void RequestSave() => _saveHandler.RequestCall();

    private void Save()
    {
        // serialize model and save it to a file
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is my current implementation:

```
public class RecurringActionHandler
{
    // Action to call recurrently 
    private readonly Action _action;

    // a lock to protect _hasTask and _isCallRequested
    private readonly object _lock = new();

    // minimum time span between two calls to _action
    private readonly TimeSpan _minimumRestTime;

    // a boolean indicating whether a task is already running or not
    private bool _hasTask;

    // a boolean indicating whether a call to _action is request or not
    private bool _isCallRequested;

    public RecurringActionHandler(Action action, TimeSpan minimumRestTime)
    {
        _action = action;
        _minimumRestTime = minimumRestTime;
    }

    public void RequestCall()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _isCallRequested = true;

            if (_hasTask)
                return;

            _hasTask = true;
            Task.Run(Work);
        }
    }

    private async Task Work()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_isCallRequested)
                {
                    _hasTask = false;
                    break;
                }

                _isCallRequested = false;
            }

            _action();
            await Task.Delay(_minimumRestTime).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for advice on the code and the method / class names. Is `Throttling` a matching name here ?

Comment: Why do you use re-entrant locking?

Comment: @PeterCsala in case of a race on `RequestCall` (two calls from two differents threads), `Task.Run` can be called twice.Which is not desirable.

Comment: [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) can prevent that to happen.

Comment: @PeterCsala locking prevent that, Double-checked locking is an optimization of locking. I don't think I need it at this point but I can add it.

Comment: `save in a file the current status` why not just lock the file itself while it's open ?

Comment: `save in a file the current status` why not just lock the file itself while it's open ?

Comment: @iSR5 that is a detail in the implementation of the `Save` method. It's not related to the subject: the idea of postpone/"merge" calls to this method.